# ExposedDropdownMenu in Night mode shows incorrect text color

Tags: material-design, material-components-android, android-night-mode

In this style "@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense.ExposedDropdownMenu" in Night mode the text of dropdown items are black. The problem exists just in Night mode, in Day mode everything is ok.

The text of items of the dropdown when opened are shown over the "colorSurface", so they should be using the "colorOnSurface" for the text. In screenshot the "colorSurface is green. The text is unchangeable and it should work correctly without having to be customized. In night mode all other aspects work correctly. When I select the item it also works by showing white text. I would expect the behavior to be like the selected item color.

In short the items in the dropdown should match the text color of the selected item. As you can also see in the screenshot I set the "colorOnSurface" to be white and it will also not change the text to white in the dropdown.

This problem happens on each device any API.

material version = '1.3.0-rc01'[https://imgur.com/a/e0Rh21h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQrof.png)

Can you give me the solution how to solve this issue please?